# How to make whitespaces disappear in HTML5

Tags: html, css, whitespace

How to remove white spaces on the sides of the page? I have set `margins` and `padding` of the elements to `0` and still the white space appears on the left, how do i make it disappear?

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening either because your `body` is not full-width or it is taking some margin/padding.

Add following to your css

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That extra spacing is coming from `body`. Try inspecting the `body` element and change its `margin` to 0.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```